# Include results but exclude the data in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (Oracle):

```
customer_quote
------
int id
int part_key (fk)
int condition_code (fk)
number unit_price
int qty_quoted
date entry_date
```

With a query that selects data from the past year:

```
SELECT cq.part_key 
    , cq.condition_code 
    , COUNT(*) AS cq_count 
    , SUM(cq.unit_price * cq.qty_quoted) AS cq_total 
    , SUM(cq.qty_quoted) cq_qty
FROM customer_quote cq 
WHERE cq.entry_date > TO_DATE('09-Jun-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
GROUP BY cq.part_key 
    , cq.condition_code
```

But I need the data to include parts with activity from the past two years but data older than 1 year shouldn't calculate into the totals. So parts without data in the last year should show up in the results but have `0, 0, 0` for the totals, like this:

```
44814   45  25  20114.1 81
41404   45  4   10237   50
31823   45  4   1050.5  17
25380   49  0   (null)  (null)
58791   46  0   (null)  (null)
13012   45  0   (null)  (null)
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: "But I need the data to include parts with activity from the past two years but data older than 1 year shouldn't calculate into the totals."  I don't get it.  One year or two years?  Include or not include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` inside the `sum`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN cq.entry_date > add_months(sysdate, -12)
         THEN cq.unit_price * cq.qty_quoted END) AS cq_total
```

If no `when` clause matches, and without an `else`, the `case` returns `null`.  And `sum` ignores `null`, so the snippet above sums only values from the last year.

Comment: So I'll need to have three `case-when` statements (1 for each of the aggregates)?

Comment: For three aggregates, yeah that's probably simplest